# How to redirect from magento site to wordpress blog using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have Magento as main site and WordPress is in blog folder.

I want to redirect to blog when someone types

```
http://www.example.com/blog/
```

However it is not redirecting to blog. I tried this om Magento's `.htaccess (root)` ...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://example.com/blog/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Please help if anything is wrong.

Comment: Can anyone help pls.?

Comment: So when I type in `http://www.example.com/blog` it is to redirect me where?